# WHY does the array execution in the function below throw an exception?

Tags: php, sql, sqlite

I'm working on a ussd voting application and Ive got everything right except for saving the votes to the database and updating the table.

The function that handles the `save_vote` is per below;

```
function save_vote($phone_number, $voted_for) {
        // Just the digits, please
        $phone_number = preg_replace('/\D/', '', $phone_number);

        // Check to see if person has already voted
        $stmt = $this->db->prepare('SELECT COUNT(*) FROM voters WHERE phone_number=?');
        $stmt->execute(array($phone_number));

        // If not, save their vote
        if ($stmt->fetchColumn() == 0)
        {
            // Save voter
            $stmt = $this->db->prepare('INSERT INTO voters (phone_number, voted_for) VALUES (?, ?)');
            $stmt->execute(array($phone_number, $voted_for));

            // Update vote count
            $stmt = $this->db->prepare('UPDATE brands SET votes = votes + 1 WHERE id=?');
            $stmt->execute(array($voted_for));

            return 'Thank you, your vote has been recorded';
        }
        else {
            return 'Sorry, you can only vote once.';
        }
    }
```

The values being passed into the function are `DB->save_vote('02778995805', 2)`

The server logs throws an exception as follows

> 1 {main}
>
> 2019-02-28T13:50:49.813224+00:00 app[web.1]:   thrown in /app/db.php on line 57

and line 57 is where the code `$stmt->execute(array($phone_number));` is at.

Will appreciate some help explaining what could be going wrong.

Thanks

As Requested from the comments, Please see below

db.php code:

```
<?php
/**
 * Created by PhpStorm.
 * User: kqwameselase
 * Date: 2019-02-27
 * Time: 22:53
 */
    class DB {
        const DB_NAME = 'votes.sqlite';

    protected $db;

    function __construct() {
        $this->db = new PDO('sqlite:'.self::DB_NAME);
    }

    function init() {
        // Create two tables, one to store the brands being voted on and their vote counts (brands) and one to store the people that have voted (voters).
        $this->db->exec('CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS brands (id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, name TEXT, votes INTEGER);');
        $this->db->exec('CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS voters (id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, phone_number TEXT, voted_for INTEGER);');
    }

    function add_brand($name) {
        // Check to make sure the brand name doesn't already exist
        $stmt = $this->db->prepare('SELECT COUNT(*) FROM brands WHERE name=?');
        $stmt->execute(array($name));

        // If not, insert it
        if ($stmt->fetchColumn() == 0)
        {
            $stmt = $this->db->prepare('INSERT INTO brands (name, votes) VALUES (?, 0)');
            $stmt->execute(array($name));
        }
    }

    function get_brands() {
        $result = $this->db->query('SELECT * FROM brands');

        foreach ($result as $row)
        {
            $brand['id'] = $row['id'];
            $brand['name'] = $row['name'];
            $brand['votes'] = $row['votes'];

            $brands[] = $brand;
        }

        return $brands;
    }

    /**
     * @param $phone_number
     * @param $voted_for
     * @return string
     */


function save_vote($phone_number, $voted_for) {
        // Just the digits, please
        $phone_number = intval(preg_replace('/\D/', '', $phone_number));

        // Check to see if person has already voted
        $stmt = $this->db->prepare('SELECT COUNT(*) FROM voters WHERE phone_number=?');
        $stmt->bindParam(1, $phone_number, PDO::PARAM_INT);
        $stmt->execute();

        // If not, save their vote
        if ($stmt->fetchColumn() == 0)
        {
            // Save voter
            $stmt = $this->db->prepare('INSERT INTO voters (phone_number, voted_for) VALUES (?, ?)');
            $stmt->bindParam(1, $phone_number, PDO::PARAM_INT);
            $stmt->bindParam(2, $voted_for, PDO::PARAM_INT);
            $stmt->execute();

            // Update vote count
            $stmt = $this->db->prepare('UPDATE brands SET votes = votes + 1 WHERE id=?');
            $stmt->bindParam(1,$voted_for, PDO::PARAM_INT);
            $stmt->execute();

            return 'Thank you, your vote has been recorded';
        }
        else {
            return 'Sorry, you can only vote once.';
        }
    }
/*        function save_vote($phone_number, $voted_for) {
            // Just the digits, please
            $phone_number = intval(preg_replace('/\D/', '', $phone_number));

        // Check to see if person has already voted
        $stmt = $this->db->prepare('SELECT COUNT(*) FROM voters WHERE phone_number=?');
        $stmt->bindParam('i', $phone_number);
        $stmt->execute();

        // If not, save their vote
        if ($stmt->fetchColumn() == 0)
        {
            // Save voter
            $stmt = $this->db->prepare('INSERT INTO voters (phone_number, voted_for) VALUES (?, ?)');
            $stmt->bindParam('ii', $phone_number, $voted_for); // we suppose tha rhe $voted_for is integer if not use intval
            $stmt->execute();

            // Update vote count
            $stmt = $this->db->prepare('UPDATE brands SET votes = votes + 1 WHERE id=?');
            $stmt->bindParam('i',$voted_for);// we suppose tha rhe $voted_for is integer if not use intval
            $stmt->execute();

            return 'Thank you, your vote has been recorded';
        }
        else {
            return 'Sorry, you can only vote once.';
        }
    }*/

/*        function save_vote($phone_number, $voted_for) {
            // Just the digits, please
            $phone_number = preg_replace('/\D/', '', $phone_number);

        // Check to see if person has already voted
        $stmt = $this->db->prepare('SELECT COUNT(*) FROM voters WHERE phone_number=?');
        $stmt->bind_param(int, $phone_number);
        $stmt->execute();
        //$stmt->execute(array($phone_number));

        // If not, save their vote
        if ($stmt->fetchColumn() == 0)
        {
            // Save voter
            $stmt = $this->db->prepare('INSERT INTO voters (phone_number, voted_for) VALUES (?, ?)');
            $stmt->execute(array($phone_number, $voted_for));

            // Update vote count
            $stmt = $this->db->prepare('UPDATE brands SET votes = votes + 1 WHERE id=?');
            $stmt->execute(array($voted_for));

            return 'Thank you, your vote has been recorded';
        }
        else {
            return 'Sorry, you can only vote once.';
        }
    }*/
}
```

Here is the Updated function that handles the save_vote

```
function save_vote($phone_number, $voted_for) {
            // Just the digits, please
            $phone_number = intval(preg_replace('/\D/', '', $phone_number));

            // Check to see if person has already voted
            //$stmt = $this->db->prepare("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM voters WHERE phone_number=?");
            //$stmt->bindValue(1, $phone_number, PDO::PARAM_INT);
            //$stmt->execute();

            //Try catch exception to check connection to Database.
            try{
                $this->db->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
                //echo "Connected !";
                //Check to see if person has already voted
                try{
                    $stmt = "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM voters WHERE phone_number=?";
                    $results = $this->db->prepare($stmt);
                    $results->bindParam(1, $phone_number, PDO::PARAM_INT);

                    //Verify execution of query
                    if($results->execute()){
                        // If number not already voted, save their vote
                        if ($results->fetchColumn() == 0)
                        {
                            // Save voter
                            $stmt2 = "INSERT INTO voters (phone_number, voted_for) VALUES (?, ?)";
                            $stmt2query = $this->db->prepare($stmt2);
                            $stmt2query->bindValue(1, $phone_number, PDO::PARAM_INT);
                            $stmt2query->bindValue(2, $voted_for, PDO::PARAM_INT);
                            $stmt2query->execute();

                            // Update vote count
                            $stmt3 = "UPDATE brands SET votes = votes + 1 WHERE id=?";
                            $stmt3query = $this->db->prepare($stmt3);
                            $stmt3query->bindValue(1,$voted_for, PDO::PARAM_INT);
                            $stmt3query->execute();

                            return 'Thank you, your vote has been recorded';
                        }
                        else {
                            return 'Sorry, you can only vote once.';
                        }
                    }
                    else {
                        return "There is some problem in updating your profile. Please contact site admin";
                    }

                }  catch (PDOException $e)  {
                    echo $e;
                    die();
                }

                //$values = $results->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);
                //echo $values;


            }  catch (PDOException $e)  {
                echo $e;
                die();
            }


        }
```

Here is the vote-now.php code where the useres interract with the system.

```
<?php
/**
 * Created by PhpStorm.
 * User: kqwameselase
 * Date: 2019-02-27
 * Time: 10:29
 */
date_default_timezone_set('Africa/Ghana');

require_once('db.php');
header('Content-type: application/json; charset=utf-8');
header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: http://apps.smsgh.com");
header("Access-Control-Allow-Methods: POST, GET, OPTIONS");



// Begin by reading the HTTP request body contents.
// Since we expect is to be in JSON format, let's parse as well.
$ussdRequest = json_decode(@file_get_contents('php://input'));

// Our response object. We shall use PHP's json_encode function
// to convert the various properties (we'll set later) into JSON.
$ussdResponse = new stdClass;

// Check if no errors occured.
if ($ussdRequest != NULL)
    switch ($ussdRequest->Type) {
        // Initiation request. This is the first type of request every
        // USSD application will receive. So let's display our main menu.
        case 'Initiation':

            $ussdResponse->Message =
                "Welcome to Ghana Beverage Awards 2019. Vote for your preferred product of the year.\n" .
                "1. Origin Beer \n2. Club Beer \n3. Star Beer \n4. Guinness \n5. Gulder";
            $ussdResponse->Type = 'Response';
            break;


        // Response request. This is where all other interactions occur.
        // Every time the mobile subscriber responds to any of our vote options,
        // this will be the type of request we shall receive.
        case 'Response':
            switch ($ussdRequest->Sequence) {

                // Menu selection. Note that everytime we receive a request
                // in a particular session, the Sequence will increase by 1.
                // Sequence number 1 was that of the initiation request.
                case 2:
                    $items = array('1' => 'Origin Beer', '2' => 'Club Beer', '3' => 'Star Beer', '4' => 'Guinness', '5' => 'Gulder');
                    if (isset($items[$ussdRequest->Message])) {
                        $ussdResponse->Message = 'Please confirm your preferred product of the year is  '
                            . $items[$ussdRequest->Message] . "?\n1. Yes\n2. No";
                        $ussdResponse->Type = 'Response';
                        $ussdResponse->ClientState = $items[$ussdRequest->Message];
                    } else {
                        $ussdResponse->Message = 'Invalid option.';
                        $ussdResponse->Type = 'Release';
                    }
                    break;

                // Order confirmation. Here the user has responded to our
                // previously sent menu (i.e. Please confirm your preferred product of the year is...)
                // Note that we saved the option the user selected in our
                // previous dialog into the ClientState property.
                case 3:
                    switch ($ussdRequest->Message) {
                        case '1':
                            $db = new DB();

                            // save_vote will check to see if the person has already voted
                            $phone_number = $ussdRequest->Mobile;

                            //Return the array number for the selected vote to be used when updated votes
                            $items2 = array('1' => 'Origin Beer', '2' => 'Club Beer', '3' => 'Star Beer', '4' => 'Guinness', '5' => 'Gulder');
                            $voted_for = array_search($ussdRequest->ClientState, $items2) ;

                            $response = $db->save_vote($phone_number, $voted_for);
                            //echo $response;

                            //Display Success message after vote saved.
                            $ussdResponse->Message =
                                'Thank you. You have successfully voted for '
                                . $ussdRequest->ClientState . ' as your preferred Product of the Year.';


                            break;
                        case '2':
                            $ussdResponse->Message = 'Vote cancelled.';
                            break;
                        default:
                            $ussdResponse->Message = 'Invalid selection.';
                            break;
                    }
                    $ussdResponse->Type = "Release";
                    break;

                // Unexpected request. If the code here should ever
                // execute, it means the request is probably forged.
                default:
                    $ussdResponse->Message = 'Unexpected request.';
                    $ussdResponse->Type = 'Release';
                    break;
            }
            break;

        // Session cleanup.
        // Not much to do here.
        default:
            $ussdResponse->Message = 'Duh.';
            $ussdResponse->Type = 'Release';
            break;
    }
// An error has occured.
// Probably the request JSON could not be parsed.
else {
    $ussdResponse->Message = 'Invalid USSD request.';
    $ussdResponse->Type = 'Release';
}
// Let's set the HTTP content-type of our response, encode our
// USSD response object into JSON, and flush the output.

header('Content-type: application/json; charset=utf-8');
echo json_encode($ussdResponse);
```

Full Error per heroku Logs:

> 2019-02-28T16:31:19.510613+00:00 app[web.1]: [28-Feb-2019 16:31:19
>   UTC] PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Error: Call to a member function
>   bindParam() on bool in /app/db.php:62 2019-02-28T16:31:19.510703+00:00
>   app[web.1]: Stack trace: 2019-02-28T16:31:19.510862+00:00 app[web.1]:
>
> ## 0 /app/vote-now.php(77): DB->save_vote(277655805, 1) 2019-02-28T16:31:19.510947+00:00 app[web.1]: #1 {main}
>
> 2019-02-28T16:31:19.511072+00:00 app[web.1]:   thrown in /app/db.php
>   on line 62 2019-02-28T16:31:19.512333+00:00 app[web.1]: 10.45.101.19 -
>   - [28/Feb/2019:16:31:19 +0000] "POST /vote-now.php HTTP/1.1" 500 - "http://apps.smsgh.com/USSDSimulator/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel
>   Mac OS X 10_14_3) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko)
>   Chrome/72.0.3626.109 Safari/537.36

Comment: Is that all the error shows?

Comment: can you show all errors logs ?

Comment: or show the code of the app/db.php

Comment: What kind of db abstraction layer are you using? Does `$stmt->execute` accept array? A little more context could be helpful.

Comment: also check what the $phone_number contain before executing the query

Comment: also try binding with $stmt->bind_param('i', $phone_number); and then call $stmt->execute() without param

Comment: Are you using `PDO`? `phone_number` is of integer type in database? When validating phone number, throw errors and stop the execution if not validated rather than just extracting the numbers from the invalidated input.

Comment: Set your PDO connection to throw exceptions: `$this->db->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);`. Then PHP should throw an exception on `prepare(...)`.

Comment: @PaulSpiegel Thats the next step after doing some additional reading from (http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.prepare.php) but id like to try your method first. How do i go about implementing the exception and displaying the error? Found some resource here (http://w3schools.invisionzone.com/topic/56892-uncaught-error-call-to-a-member-function-bindparam-on-boolean/) will give it a shot and revert. Thanks.

Comment: @Selase you never call the `init()` method on the database object (`$db->init()`), which creates the tables in the SQLite database.  If those tables don't exist, you'll get the errors that you mentioned.     If you haven't already, put Paul Spiegel's "setAttribute" line inside your DB class (e.g. on the line after `$this->db = new PDO(...)`) to help expose this as a problem.

Answer (score -1):

Prepared statements can't accept arrays in the `execute()` function. You'll need to bind each parameter like so (replace the "s" with the data type you want, i.e. string, int, etc):

```
$stmt = $this->db->prepare('SELECT COUNT(*) FROM voters WHERE phone_number=?');
$stmt->bind_param("s", $phone_number);
$stmt->execute();
```

Comment: What if he uses PDO as abstraction layer? `execute()` method accepts array in PDO abstraction. Also, if he uses `int` or `bigint` data type for phone number, he will have to use `i` in `bind_param()`.

Comment: I edited my code as below and would like to know if its correct?
    // Check to see if person has already voted
       $stmt = $this->db->prepare('SELECT COUNT(*) FROM voters 
    WHERE phone_number=?');
                $stmt->bind_param(int, $phone_number);
                $stmt->execute();

Comment: It should be `$stmt->bind_param('i', $phone_number);` as @Wolverine said.

Comment: @Selase Are you using PDO?

Comment: Yes Please @Wolverine. You may suggest an alternative that'd work best and teach me how to implement it should in case PDO will prove to be stubborn.

Comment: If you are using PDO, this `$stmt->bind_param('i', $phone_number);`  wouldn't be the correct syntax because that is used with MySQLi.

Comment: @Wolverine I noticed that as intellisense highlighted it and suggested the right syntax which i tried `$stmt->bindParam('parameter', '$variable', 'Data type');` but that didnt work either. i also tried the `bindValue` syntax and got the same issue so im begining to think the problem may be elsewhere and not with the syntax but the server keeps pointing me back to the same block

Comment: Actually, I meant that PDO and MySQLi syntax vary for `bindParam` function. I just noticed the question is updated.

Comment: Is this the line `$stmt->bindParam(1, $phone_number, PDO::PARAM_INT);` you're getting error?

Comment: @Wolvering Yes. thats the line where the error is thrown.

Answer (score -1):

I think you are not using the types as needed -> I'm using the updated code you entered:

Two problems I see:

1. Phone number is a string and not an integer.
2. You are expecting `$ussdRequest->Mobile` to be an **int but it gives a string**.
3. If you are saving phone numbers as Numbers I recommend to switch to characters...

But to be sure we need your table structure + the `$ussdRequest` class for further inspection.

**Try to use this**:

```
$stmt2query->bindParam(1, $phone_number.'';, PDO::PARAM_STR);
$stmt2query->bindParam(2, intval($voted_for), PDO::PARAM_INT);
```

The `.''` and `intval()` are just there to make sure you are passing the correct types, If it works than rethink your types and check where the conversion happens...

Hope I helped.